# Pass selected gridview value to detailsview template field in edit Mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, detailsview

`DetailsView1` shows master detail from selected record of `GridView1`.

In edit mode, I have included a functionality for search, where on user click, `GridView2` visibility is enabled.

I would like to have data from a selected row value (eg "accountnumber") from `GridView2` loaded into a textbox control in `DetailsView1` when I want to update "accountnumber".

How can I achieve this using VB.NET?

Comment: Please use line breaks to format your question and show some exiting code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to include line breaks and inline code formatting to improve readability. Please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the question to include any relevant code that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I need a solution as well, now that readability is improved

Answer (score 1):

I put together a few ideas to come up with this, which worked perfectly well.

```
    Dim TextBox As TextBox = TryCast(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
    TextBox.Text = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text
```